# Enable compiler output pane in Codeblocks

Tags: ide, codeblocks

This is probably a really noob question, but the fact of the matter is that my Code::blocks wouldn't show me errors when it compiles - it only shows a red bar next to the offending line as shown in screenshot. Also, when my code does run and has output, CB opens a new window instead of showing the output in a pane in the bottom of the editor window like some other IDEs. How do I enable either/both, since they're probably the same feature? Thanks![image]

Comment: Also, your Code Blocks is rather old (version 8). There is a 10.05.

Comment: My GCC doesn't work with v10 for some reason :(

Comment: gcc that comes with C::B v8 is also rather old, 3.4.x I believe. I encourage you to download the nightly builds of C::B and give it a try. There's been a vast amount of improvement done on the IDE.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Press F2 to enable Logs panel. Select "Build log" in it.

Or go to menu: `View -> Logs`

Have a good developing!

Comment: they have to rename it. I searched in all menu. it is difficult to guess. I think many people get this problem in codeblocks. It is better to move it to a menu called 'window' to match in other IDEs

Answer (score 4):

go to view -> perspective -> and enable code::Blocks default, you can see your projects left side and down the build logs and messages etc.

Answer (score 2):

If after hitting F2, you don't see "Log & others" tab

You need choose: "View" ==> "Perspective" ==> "Delete current"

Answer (score 0):

You just need to hit F2 to enable the "log & others" pane.

Answer (score 0):

Steps :View ->Perspective ->Delete
works definitely, if F2 and view logs don't work.